# How does the Bessel Function of the First Kind solve the Bessel Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am aiming to prove that the Bessel function of the First Kind, $J_\nu (x)$, satisfies the Bessel Equation by direct substitution for any value of parameter $\nu$.

$J_\nu(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m + \nu + 1)}\left(\dfrac x2\right)^{2m+\nu}$

It seems to be a simple matter of differentiating the Function twice and substititing into the Bessel Equation, but I can't seem to get it to solve to 0 as it ought to do if the Function is a solution.

Also, apologies for any janky use of the MathJax tools, first time posting and on a mobile, at the moment.

Comment: How are you defining $J_n$ to perform the appropriate derivatives? By series expansion?

Comment: I have no idea how to put it into MathJax and not in much state to try currently, but it's the sum of an infinite series form. Can post a more detailed comment tomorrow, if needed. Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: To get you started, here is the version found in Wikipedia in Mathjax: $$J_\nu(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m + \nu + 1)}\left(\dfrac x2\right)^{2m+\nu}$$ You can see how it is formatted (and copy it) by right-clicking on the formula and choosing "Show Math As" > "TeX Commands".

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Added it to my original question.